# If form is empty, resturn error0 to index,php

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

This is my code to check for multiple inputs of a form.

However, I cannot get it to dis an error when the form is empty. So far, trying to enter this page from index.php causes it to return to index.php again.

(my guess is that at even before entering the values in the form, php is already determining them as being empty, so send me back?)

How can I display the form first, then have php check if the POST is not set, return me back to index.php with the error in the session?

Thanks!

```
   <?php

    // session for POST success and error messages
    session_start();

    require_once "db.php";

    if ( isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b']) 
         && isset($_POST['c'])) {

        $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']);
        $b = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b']);
        $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c']);

        if (preg_match('/\-*\d+\.*\d*/',$b) && preg_match('/\-*\d+\.*\d*/',$c) &&
            (-10 <= $b && 10 >= $b) && (-20 <= $c && 20 >= $c)) {

            [some code checking for different conditions...]

    } elseif (!isset($_POST['a']) | !isset($_POST['b']) | !isset($_POST['c'])) {

            $_SESSION['error'] = $_POST['error0'];
            header('Location: index.php') ;
            return;
    }

    ?>


<form method="post">
<p>A:
<input type="text" name="a"></p>
<p>B:
<input type="text" name="b"></p>
<p>C:
<input type="text" name="c"></p>

<!--Sending POST for success-->
<input type="hidden" name="success" value="Record Added">

<input type="hidden" name="error0" value="All values are required">

<p><input type="submit" value="Add New"/>

<a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

Solved: Got rid of elseif and added another condition within if

```
} elseif (strlen($a) == 0 | strlen($b) == 0 | strlen($c) == 0) { 

    $_SESSION['error'] = $_POST['error0'];
    header('Location: index.php') ;
    return;
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post vars may be set but are empty so check for length as well as `isset`

`strlen(trim($_POST['a']))`

Assuming, of course, that you don't want empty values.

```
if ( ( isset($_POST['a']) && strlen(trim($_POST['a'])) ) && ( isset($_POST['b'] && strlen(trim($_POST['b'])) ) )
```

Comment: gave me the idea to get rid of the elseif and add another condition inside the if checking for length

Answer (score 1):

|| not only one

```
elseif (!isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['b']) || !isset($_POST['c'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [logical or](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) instead. so:

```
elseif (!isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['b']) || !isset($_POST['c']))
```